# HTML and JavaScript Image Slideshow only links to the same hyperlink rather than different ones for each image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am creating an image slideshow in HTML and I want each image to link to a different webpage and each image to show a different title/alt tag. However the code I am using is only giving me one link and one title rather than different ones.

I have tried to ways of doing it now but neither seem to work. I will post the first way now and the second way in a different message so we don't get confused.

In the html file the code is as following:

```
div id="slideShowImages">
    <a href = "civil_war.html"><img src="Images/civil_war.jpg" alt = "Captain America: Civil War" title = "Captain America: Civil War"/></a>
    <a href = "agents_of_shield.html"><img src = "Images/agents_of_shield.jpg" alt = "Agents of Shield" title="Agents of Shield"/> </a>
    <a href = "fantastic_four.html"><img src = "Images/fantastic_four.jpg" alt ="The Fantastic Four" title = "The Fantastic Four"/></a>
    <a href = "jurassic_world.html"><img src = "Images/jurassic_world.jpg" alt = "Jurassic World" title = "Jurassic World"/></a>
    <a href = "Furious_7.html"><img src="Images/paul_walker.jpg" alt = "Paul Walker in Furious 7" title = "Paul Walker in Furious 7"/></a>
</div>
<script src="slideShow.js"></script>
```

The code in the slideShow.js are as follows:

```
    window.addEventListener('load', slideShow, false);

    function slideShow() {



    var globals = {
    slideDelay: 6000, // The time interval between consecutive slides.
    fadeDelay: 35, // The time interval between individual opacity changes. This  should always be much smaller than slideDelay.  
    wrapperID: "slideShowImages", // The ID of the <div> element that contains all of the <img> elements to be shown as a slide show.
    buttonID: "slideShowButton", // The ID of the <button> element that toggles the slide show on and off.
    buttonStartText: "Start Slides", // Text used in the slide show toggle button.
    buttonStopText: "Stop Slides", // Text used in the slide show toggle button.    
    wrapperObject: null, // Will contain a reference to the <div> element that contains all of the <img> elements to be shown as a slide show.
    buttonObject: null, // If present, will contain a reference to the <button> element that toggles the slide show on and off. The initial assumption is that there is no such button element (hence the false value).
    slideImages: [], // Will contain all of the slide image objects.
    slideShowID: null, // A setInterval() ID value used to stop the slide show.
    slideShowRunning: true, // Used to record when the slide show is running and when it's not. The slide show is always initially running.    
    slideIndex: 0 // The index of the current slide image.
  }

  /* MAIN *************************************************************************************************/

  initializeGlobals();  

  if ( insufficientSlideShowMarkup() ) {
    return; // Insufficient slide show markup - exit now.
  }

   // Assert: there's at least one slide image.

  if (globals.slideImages.length == 1) {
    return; // The solo slide image is already being displayed - exit now.
  }

  // Assert: there's at least two slide images.

  initializeSlideShowMarkup();

  globals.wrapperObject.addEventListener('click', toggleSlideShow, false); // If the user clicks a slide show image, it toggles the slide show on and off.

  if (globals.buttonObject) {
    globals.buttonObject.addEventListener('click', toggleSlideShow, false); // This callback is used to toggle the slide show on and off.
  } 

  startSlideShow();

  /* FUNCTIONS ********************************************************************************************/

  function initializeGlobals() {   
    globals.wrapperObject = (document.getElementById(globals.wrapperID) ? document.getElementById(globals.wrapperID) : null);
    globals.buttonObject = (document.getElementById(globals.buttonID) ? document.getElementById(globals.buttonID) : null);   

    if (globals.wrapperObject) {
      globals.slideImages = (globals.wrapperObject.querySelectorAll('img') ? globals.wrapperObject.querySelectorAll('img') : []);
    }
  } // initializeGlobals

  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

  function insufficientSlideShowMarkup() {
    if (!globals.wrapperObject) { // There is no wrapper element whose ID is globals.wrapperID - fatal error.
      if (globals.buttonObject) {
        globals.buttonObject.style.display = "none"; // Hide the not needed slide show button element when present.
      }
      return true;
    }

    if (!globals.slideImages.length) { // There needs to be at least one slide <img> element - fatal error.
      if (globals.wrapperObject) {
        globals.wrapperObject.style.display = "none"; // Hide the not needed <div> wrapper element.
      }

      if (globals.buttonObject) {
        globals.buttonObject.style.display = "none"; // Hide the not needed slide show button element.
      }

      return true;
    }

    return false; // The markup expected by this library seems to be present.
  } // insufficientSlideShowMarkup

  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

  function initializeSlideShowMarkup() {  
    var slideWidthMax = maxSlideWidth(); // Returns a value that is always in pixel units.
    var slideHeightMax = maxSlideHeight(); // Returns a value that is always in pixel units.

    globals.wrapperObject.style.position = "relative";
    globals.wrapperObject.style.overflow = "hidden"; // This is just a safety thing.
    globals.wrapperObject.style.width = slideWidthMax + "px";
    globals.wrapperObject.style.height = slideHeightMax + "px";

    var slideCount = globals.slideImages.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) { 
      globals.slideImages[i].style.opacity = 0;
      globals.slideImages[i].style.position = "absolute";
      globals.slideImages[i].style.top = (slideHeightMax - globals.slideImages[i].getBoundingClientRect().height) / 2 + "px";   
      globals.slideImages[i].style.left = (slideWidthMax - globals.slideImages[i].getBoundingClientRect().width) / 2 + "px";               
    }

    globals.slideImages[0].style.opacity = 1; // Make the first slide visible.

    if (globals.buttonObject) {
      globals.buttonObject.textContent = globals.buttonStopText;
    }
  } // initializeSlideShowMarkup

  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

  function maxSlideWidth() {
    var maxWidth = 0;
    var maxSlideIndex = 0;
    var slideCount = globals.slideImages.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) {
      if (globals.slideImages[i].width > maxWidth) {
        maxWidth = globals.slideImages[i].width; // The width of the widest slide so far.
        maxSlideIndex = i; // The slide with the widest width so far.
      }
    }

    return globals.slideImages[maxSlideIndex].getBoundingClientRect().width; // Account for the image's border, padding, and margin values. Note that getBoundingClientRect() is always in units of pixels.
  } // maxSlideWidth

  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

  function maxSlideHeight() {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    var maxSlideIndex = 0;    
    var slideCount = globals.slideImages.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) {
      if (globals.slideImages[i].height > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = globals.slideImages[i].height; // The height of the tallest slide so far.
        maxSlideIndex = i; // The slide with the tallest height so far.
      }
    }

    return globals.slideImages[maxSlideIndex].getBoundingClientRect().height; // Account for the image's border, padding, and margin values. Note that getBoundingClientRect() is always in units of pixels.
  } // maxSlideHeight

  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

  function startSlideShow() {
    globals.slideShowID = setInterval(transitionSlides, globals.slideDelay);                
  } // startSlideShow

  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

  function haltSlideShow() {
    clearInterval(globals.slideShowID);   
  } // haltSlideShow

  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

  function toggleSlideShow() {
    if (globals.slideShowRunning) {
      haltSlideShow();
      if (globals.buttonObject) { 
        globals.buttonObject.textContent = globals.buttonStartText; 
      }
    }
    else {
      startSlideShow();
      if (globals.buttonObject) { 
        globals.buttonObject.textContent = globals.buttonStopText; 
      }            
    }
    globals.slideShowRunning = !(globals.slideShowRunning);
  } // toggleSlideShow

  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

  function transitionSlides() {
    var currentSlide = globals.slideImages[globals.slideIndex];

    ++(globals.slideIndex);
    if (globals.slideIndex >= globals.slideImages.length) {
      globals.slideIndex = 0;
    }

    var nextSlide = globals.slideImages[globals.slideIndex];

    var currentSlideOpacity = 1; // Fade the current slide out.
    var nextSlideOpacity = 0; // Fade the next slide in.
    var opacityLevelIncrement = 1 / globals.fadeDelay;
    var fadeActiveSlidesID = setInterval(fadeActiveSlides, globals.fadeDelay);

    function fadeActiveSlides() {
      currentSlideOpacity -= opacityLevelIncrement;
      nextSlideOpacity += opacityLevelIncrement;

      // console.log(currentSlideOpacity + nextSlideOpacity); // This should always be very close to 1.

      if (currentSlideOpacity >= 0 && nextSlideOpacity <= 1) {
        currentSlide.style.opacity = currentSlideOpacity;
        nextSlide.style.opacity = nextSlideOpacity; 
      }
      else {
        currentSlide.style.opacity = 0;
        nextSlide.style.opacity = 1; 
        clearInterval(fadeActiveSlidesID);
      }        
    } // fadeActiveSlides
  } // transitionSlides

} // slideShow
```

If anyone could advise me on what needs doing to fix this it would be greatly appreciated. You can swap the code and use a complete alternative method if it will work.

Many Thanks Guys!

Comment: actually no it doesnt

Comment: It does although I linked them to individual ones only the last one is working so it will only link it to Furious_7.html and the title is only "Paul Walker in Furious 7" This is the problem as I thought that it would work.

Comment: same happened to me locally - only the last one showing

Comment: @RachelGallen I did have it working a few months ago but I lost my USB with it all on and then having not touched HTML in several months my mind has went completely blanks as to how I did it last time.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdJoWB tada!

Comment: Thank you very much! So will I put the js in <head> or in its own file and then call the script?

Comment: you could do either - i put it in a separate file

Comment: why did you un-accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key is to put them in separate `divs`. (snippet needs jquery) Look at [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdJoWB)

```js
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

```css
#slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 240px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
<div>
    <a href= "http://www.musicmatters.ie/index.html"><img src = "http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/bara2.jpg" width="240" height="240" alt = "Agents of Shield" title="Agents of Shield"/> </a>
    </div>
    <div>
    <a href= "http://www.musicmatters.ie/about.html"><img src = "http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/bara3.jpg" width="240" height="240" alt ="The Fantastic Four" title= "The Fantastic Four"/></a>
    </div>
    <div>
    <a href= "http://www.musicmatters.ie/singingamach.html"><img src = "http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/singingamach.jpg" width="240" height="240" alt = "Jurassic World" title = "Jurassic World"/></a>
    </div>
    <div>
    <a href= "http://www.musicmatters.ie/contact.html"><img src="bara4.jpg" alt ="Paul Walker in Furious 7" width="240" height="240" title ="Paul Walker in Furious 7"/></a>
</div>

</div>
```

[Reference](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-auto-playing-slideshow/)

EDIT:

ADD these classes to your main.css

```
#slideshow { 
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    position: relative; 
    width: 860px; 
    height: 470px; 
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:0px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left:0px;
    right: 0px;  
}
```

and rename your div to #slideshow. Put your images in  tags and the slideshow will work See [here](http://rachelgallen.com/website/index.html)

Comment: @Rachel_Gallen Just ran this with my site and to the sizes I want except now its messed my site up!

Comment: @AdamBirds well whats the problem? post link to site btw i voted you up

Comment: The link to all the webfiles is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ue32kbdr7h21kn/Website.zip?dl=0 

When I edited the js file to what you put and amneded the divs and updated he css. It displayed all 5 of them in a row rather than as a slideshow

Comment: @AdamBirds please see my updated answer. Dont forget to put width="860" height="470" in your img tags (so that it will fit in the wrapper)